# mongodb complex aggregation nested conditional groupby

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

I have an collection of orders, which look like this:

```
[
  {
    _id: ObjectID,
    date: Date,
    products: [
      {
        id: string,
        quantity: number
      },
      {
        id: string,
        quantity: number
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

I need to aggregate them so that I can determine, using a product.id, the quantity of each id for each date (not time)

My resultant data set would look something similar to this:

```
[
  { 
    date: "2021-01-1", 
    products: {
      // product_id: quantity
      PRODUCT_ID_1: 4
      PRODUCT_ID_2: 9
    } 
  }
]
```

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$dateToString` convert date to specific your required format
- `$unwind` deconstruct `products` array
- `$group` by `id`, `date` and sum `quantity`
- `$group` by only date and construct products array in key-value format
- `$arrayToObject` convert `products` array to object

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      date: {
        $dateToString: {
          date: "$date",
          format: "%Y-%m-%d"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$products" },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        date: "$date",
        id: "$products.id"
      },
      quantity: { $sum: "$products.quantity" }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.date",
      products: {
        $push: {
          k: "$_id.id",
          v: "$quantity"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      products: { $arrayToObject: "$products" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6qyIHdcbCEu)